# How can I send a file from the Files app to my app without starting a new activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

I'm working on a mapping app and currently setting up the functionality to import both GPX and KML files. I have set up my Manifest to handle the intent to send a file from Files:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" />
</intent-filter>`
```

I have set my `launchMode` to singleTop.

I handle the new intent this way:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val intent = Intent(this, this::class.java).apply {
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT)
    }
    startActivity(intent)
    if (getIntent().action != null) {
        when (getIntent().action) {
            Intent.ACTION_SEND -> {
                val sendIntent = getIntent()
                val uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                    sendIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri::class.java)
                } else {
                    sendIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)
                }
                if (uri != null) {
                    viewModel.importManager.importFromFiles(uri)
                }
            }
        }
    }
//...
}
```

(I tried to use `override fun onNewIntent`, but for some reason the intent would revert to just MainActivity without the SEND intent by the time it reached this function. I would love an explanation on that as well if anyone knows!!)

When sending a file from the Files app, it correctly uses the current activity if it is running. However, when I go back to the Files app, it is running my app.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: "but for some reason the intent would revert to just MainActivity without the SEND intent by the time it reached this function" -- you are probably using the wrong `Intent`. Use the one that is passed as a parameter to `onNewIntent()`. "I have set up my Manifest to handle the intent to send a file from Files" -- no, that is to pretend that you are an operating system app that handles `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, which is *very* unlikely to be what you want. Only the `ACTION_SEND` part is correct.

Comment: "I handle the new intent this way" -- remove the `startActivity()` call and the lines that precede it.